# Autowired bean giving Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring, autowired

I am using Autowired annotation in a Service class to inject Dao dependency. The code I have written is:

```
public interface Service {
 public List<String> getAllCountries() ;
}
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

@Autowired
private TestDao testDao;

public TestDao getTestDao() {
    return testDao;
}

public void setTestDao(TestDao testDao) {
    this.testDao = testDao;
}

public List<String> getAllCountries() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("coming in here:" + testDao);
    return testDao.getAllCountries();
 }
}
public interface TestDao {
 List<String> getAllCountries() ;
}
 public class TestDaoImpl implements TestDao{

@Override
public List<String> getAllCountries() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    ls.add("test1");
    return ls;
  }

}
 And a controller      
   public class TestController {
   public void doSth() {
     Service service = new ServiceImpl();
     try {
        System.out.println("service obj:" + service);
        List<String> list = service.getAllCountries();
     } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Beans.xml:

```
   <context:annotation-config/>
   <bean id="controller" class="org.test.TestController"/>   
   <bean id="testDao" class="org.test.TestDaoImpl"/>

And a main class:

   ApplicationContext context = new         
          ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans4.xml");
    TestController obj= (TestController) context.getBean("controller");                                                                                                                    

    obj.doSth();
```

But it is throwing `NullPointerException` in ServiceImpl class. These all classes are in the same package.

Can somebody help me understand what exactly is the issue?

**Solution:**
        public class TestController {

```
    @Autowired
    Service service;
   //remaining code as it is
   }
```

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `ServiceImpl` in your controller, spring will not inject anything into it. Your `ServiceImpl` needs to be a spring managed bean to and injected into the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Your Service class is not managed by Spring . Hence, the dependency is getting injected.

To make your service class managed,

You can use `@Service` stereo type annotation and do a component scan.

I mean,

```
package com;
@Service
    public class ServiceImpl implement XXXX{
       //Your changes
    }
```

and in spring config file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `testDao` dependency bean has not been injected and **you need the Spring container that you are using annotations and also specify which packages need to be scanned** for Autowiring by adding the following:

`<context:annotation-config />`

`<context:component-scan base-package="org.test" />`

You can look [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) on how you can auto wire spring beans.

Comment: Thanks. But even after adding <<context:annotation-config/> in xml file, it does not work.

Comment: Can you add your complete beans.xml? Any errors in xml?

Comment: Below is the XML:'<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
 <context:annotation-config />
 <bean id="controller" class="org.test.TestController" />
 <bean id="testDao" class="org.test.TestDaoImpl" />
</beans> '

Comment: Add `<context:component-scan base-package="org.test" />` to XML file, it will work

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any bean declaration or annotation for the ServiceImpl.

```
//You canot do it like the following
@controller
class A{

ServiceImpl simp=new ServiceImpl();
}
class ServiceImpl{
@Autowired
Adao adoa;//throws NPE
}

//it should be like this
@Controller
class A{
@autowired
ServiceImpl simp;
}
@Service
class ServiceImpl{
@Autowired
Adao adoa;
}

@Repository
class Adao{
}
```

Comment: I am instantiating ServiceImpl reference in the controller class manually. The problem is with the TestDao class.

Comment: instantiating ServiceImpl reference in the controller class manually will not get instance of testDao. Either you should use the annotation or create a bean in configuration.

Comment: Thanks.The issue is fixed.